# Magento Soap API Service Unavailable

Tags: php, web-services, magento, soap

I have to connect to a shipping company for my online store using **Magento Soap API**. I cannot get the two to connect. I get The

`request failed with HTTP status 503: Service Unavailable`.

I have tried to turn off **WS-I** Compliance as well as **WSDL** and still nothing. It seems like the API service is not working. I have SOAP enabled on my server. If I try to visit the API service in my browser it redirects to my index page and never loads any SOAP XML. If I turn both **WS-I** and **WSDL** I get an error of

`Procedure 'login' not present`.

I cannot seem to get this figured out and running out of options.

Comment: It seems I was using the wrong URL of /index.php/api/soap instead of the correct url of /index.php/api/soap?wsdl

Comment: I am now having another notification that says "possible soap mismatch"

Comment: are you using wsdl in the url ?

Comment: Yes I'm using https://wwbsite.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl

Comment: remove wsdl from the url and run it again, your error should be sorted ..

Comment: I removed wsdl and I still get the error.

Comment: Try clearing your cache. Specially wsdl cache ...